# Is there a Python function that counts all the items in a word, in one go?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm trying to encode a string into a new string, with '(' if the character appears only once (in the original string) and ')' the character appears more than once (in the original string). My problem is when I go through the string sometimes a repeated character only counts as 1. I'm definitely going the wrong way.

What I've tried to do was to do a nested for loop with an if else statement, I'll provide my code below.

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    replace = [')' if word.count(i) > 1 else '(' for i in word]
    strreplace = ''.join(replace)
    print(strreplace)

a = input("Insert string here: ")
duplicate_encode(a)
```

The most notable example is with the string 'Success'. The result was supposed to be ')())())' and what I get is '(())())'. I've also tried to make it another way and use a print inside while counting the letters, and the first 'S' always counts as 1, while the last two 's' count as 2.

Comment: Upper and lower case are not the same character.

Comment: Hm, ok, let me try something then, be right back.

Comment: Ok, that solved it, thanks.

Comment: Note: `word.count(i)` of every letter `i` is not very efficient `O(n^2)`. You could look into `collections.Counter()` to do this in `O(n)`.

Comment: Be aware that some languages don't have case, and some that do, don't necessarily have every letter *in* every case. German used to be an example of this: the word *straße* means *street* but in uppercase is spelled *STRASSE* as there was no uppercase ß. [There is now, since 2008 (Unicode) and 2017 (officialdom).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the characters to be counted case-insensitively, convert the input string to one case before the loop.

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    replace = [')' if word.count(i) > 1 else '(' for i in word]
    strreplace = ''.join(replace)
    print(strreplace)
```